# TableViewCell Content is disappearing

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin, tableview, instagram

I have created an Instagram Client type application using Xamarin. When I initially run the App it shows the first 4 or 5 and when I scroll all the way down all the cells disappear and display null. Here is how the cells are supposed to appear:

**TableView.cs**

```
public class TableView : UITableView, ITableCellProvider<Datum>
    {
        public TableView ()
        {
        }

        public TableView (IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
        {
        }

        public UITableViewCell GetCell (Datum item)
        {
            var newCell = this.DequeueReusableCell(InstagramCell.Key) 
                as InstagramCell ?? InstagramCell.Create();

            newCell.Bind (item);

            return newCell;
        }

        public float GetHeightForRow (NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            return 340f;
        }

    }
```

**InstagramCell.cs**

```
public partial class InstagramCell : UITableViewCell
{
    private Datum datum;

    public static readonly UINib Nib = UINib.FromName ("InstagramCell", NSBundle.MainBundle);
    public static readonly NSString Key = new NSString ("InstagramCell");

    public InstagramCell (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {
    }

    public static InstagramCell Create()
    {
        return (InstagramCell)Nib.Instantiate (null, null) [0];
    }

    public void Bind(Datum datum)
    {
        this.datum = datum;
        if (this.datum == null || this.datum.caption == null)
        {
            this.TextLabel.Text = "null";
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            this.captionLabel.Text = datum.caption.text;

        }
        Task.Factory.StartNew (async () => {
            this.pictureImage.InvokeOnMainThread (() => this.pictureImage.SetImage (
                url: new NSUrl (datum.images.standard_resolution.url)
                )
            );

            this.profileImage.InvokeOnMainThread (() => this.profileImage.SetImage (
                url: new NSUrl (datum.user.profile_picture)
                )
            );
        });
        this.nameLabel.Text = this.datum.user == null ? "user is null" : datum.user.full_name;
    }
}
```

I have used [SimplyMobile](https://github.com/sami1971/SimplyMobile) to create the cell content. ITableCellProvider is a subclass of [SimplyMobile](https://github.com/sami1971/SimplyMobile). I am also using `MonoTouch.dialog` and `System.Threading.Tasks` in `InstagramCell.cs`. In my MainViewController.xib I subclass the TableView object under the `TableView.cs` class. Sorry for the confusion :)

Comment: Please add more info, the code sample that you provided didn't give a enough info. Can you add the code of the GetCell method?

Comment: @choper I have added the get cell class

Comment: The method above the get cell is the bind method @choper

Comment: What do you mean by "get cell is the bind method"? At all it's not the standard GetCell methods and it doesn't seem that you have override if you are using not standard UITableViewSource then inform about this, because what I see now can not work with UITableViewSource

Comment: @choper I gave the full classes and descriptions. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

TableViews are very special. They re-use cells that are defined in your ViewController (or wherever you initiate your TableViewSource). This means that, if you use a single file that defines a cell, and have a long TableView, where you need to scroll down to see the rest of the TableView, the TableViewSource will call certain methods in its base class. The data inside the cells' Textfields or ImageViews, or whatever, doesn't get cached. Instead, most of the time, the data will return to its default value, as defined in the re-useable cell file. Sometimes, it gets even more funky, and data that you entered in one of the top cells, gets copied to a cell down the TableView as you're scrolling. An option is to define a cache, like a List, where you can put the data you enter in the TextFields, and use overrides of the methods of the TableViews main class to your advantage, to fill the list, and in the end, put the values in your cache back into the right cell.

I have a lot of trouble with this as well, but try hard and think things through, and you'll eventually get it!

Hope this helps.

Good luck!